# Trouble running Jasmine specs headless

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jasmine, jasmine-headless-webkit

I'm trying to get Jasmine to run in the command line (headless), but have had no success. With our current configuration:

Gemfile:

```
gem 'jasmine', :git => "git://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-gem.git"
gem 'jasmine-headless-webkit', :git => "git://github.com/johnbintz/jasmine-headless-webkit.git"
```

My current configuration of jasmine specs runs in the browser. `rake jasmine:ci`, however, opens a browser, and then aborts shortly thereafter with this error message:

```
/Users/`<me>`/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:79:in `connect_until_stable': unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
```

I looked at the github page for [jasmine-headless-webkit](https://github.com/johnbintz/jasmine-headless-webkit), and saw that the project is listed as dead. So! I tried to replace the jasmine & jasmine-headless-webkit gem with `jasmine-rails`, and I got this error:

```
ERROR: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'jasmine.Matchers.prototype')
TRACE:
 -> file:///Users/<me>/<myapp>/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 711
 -> file:///Users/<me>/<myapp>/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 736
 -> file:///Users/<me>/<myapp>/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 738
 -> file:///Users/<me>/<myapp>/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 862
rake aborted!
Error executing command: "/Users/<me>/.phantomjs/1.9.7/darwin/bin/phantomjs" "/Users/<me>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/jasmine-rails-0.9.0/lib/jasmine_rails/../assets/javascripts/jasmine-runner.js" "/Users/<me>/<myapp>/tmp/jasmine/runner.html?spec="
```

Comment: Similar issue here (the browser opens, and I get the same issue of missing jasmine.Matchers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since most users seemed to want to run their jasmine specs using phantom, as part of the 2.0 release we made that the default. The ability to run `jasmine:ci` with selenium was extracted into [its own gem](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine_selenium_runner).

Comment: hey, thanks! :) I ended up upgrading our entire js test suite to Jasmine 2.0, which fixed the problem I was having.